# multiple associations between 2 models - Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations

I am trying to have one to many and many to many relationship between 2 models in a CMS application.
Situation being the following.

1. owner(user) has many contents, content has a owner
2. user has many contents, content has many users

my models are as follows:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :mycontent, :class_name => "Content", :as => "owner"
  has_many :content_users
  has_many :contents, :through => :content_users
end

class Content < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_attached_file :attachment 
  belongs_to :owner, :class_name => "User"
  has_many :content_users
  has_many :users, :through => :content_users
end
```

for some reason this is not working correctly for me.
please help.
thank you.

Comment: Could you elaborate on "not working correctly" a bit?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It would really helped if you explained your problem, but for now I think, it's the `:as => "owner" part. As stated in [this][1] guide`:as` is used for polymorphic associations (*With polymorphic associations, a model can belong to more than one other model, on a single association* - like comments model can be associated with news and articles).

So instead of `:as` you should use `:foreign_key => 'owner_id'`